# Coverting Tab Delimited file to CSV

Tags: python, file-conversion

I am trying to load a file in Python (3.7) and use it to generate a few plots.
the file is tab delimited (.dat extension).
I somehow managed to convert this file to a .csv file but then the header is shifted by 1 column.
Please help !

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('p2s-a 062019.dat', delimiter = '\t')

df.to_csv('p2s-a 062019.csv', encoding = 'utf-8', index = False)

newdf = pd.read_csv('p2s-a 062019.csv')

newdf
```

**Image attached**

[Table with header offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8DwJ.png)

Comment: Image seems fine to me, what output did you expect?

Comment: after reading the file use `df.columns` to set the columns

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the start of your .dat file, but it would appear the first column is called "Date Time" (with a space, or perhaps a comma) and that's causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
df.columns = list(df.columns[1:]) + ["to_delete"]

df.drop("to_delete", axis=1)
```

It'll shift all the columns by one, and delete the extra one that you don't need at the end.